# How is a quadratic form and symmetric bi-linear form determine each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quadratic-forms, multilinear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $(\neq 2)$. Let $V$ be a $k$-vector space.

A quadratic form on the vector space $V$ is a map $q:V\rightarrow k$ such that $q(c\cdot v)=c^2q(v)$.

A symmetric bilinear form on $V$ is a map $b:V\times V \rightarrow k$ such that it is linear with respect to each variable.

Now corresponding to a bilinear symmetric form $b$ one can define a quadratic form $q_b(v):=b(v,v)$.

Now, most of the places they say corresponding to a quadratic form $q$, one can define a symmetric bilinear form $b_q(v,w):=\frac{1}{2}(q(v+w)-q(v)-q(w))$.

***I don't see why $b_q$ should be bilinear. *** Am I missing something?

Comment: I think there's more to a quadratic form than that - $q(x,y)=x^3/y$ isn't a quadratic form (I think) but does satisfy what you give.

Comment: @πr8 is right. For this particular $q$ (with the added clause $q(x,y) = 0$ if $y = 0$), $b_q(e_1,e_1+e_2) = 2 \neq 0.5 = b_q(e_1,e_1) + b_q(e_1,e_2)$, so $b_q$ is not bilinear. By $e_1$ and $e_2$ I mean the canonical basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

As said in a comment there's more than what you think in the definition of a quadratic form. The general definition is the following:

> Let $R$ be a ring, $V$ an $R$-module. a map $q\colon V\longrightarrow R$ is *quadratic* if
>
> 1. for all $v\in V$, $c\in R$, $q(cv)=c^2q(v)$;
> 2. the map $B\colon V\times V\longrightarrow R$ defined by $$B(u,v)=q(u+v)-q(u)-q(v)$$ is a bilinear form (necessarily
>    symmetric).

Comment: So, bilinearity doesn't comes free, the definition demands it. Correct?

Comment: Absolutely.  $ $

Comment: Actually, I was following a lecture note on quadratic forms (http://math.uga.edu/~pete/quadraticforms.pdf), where the author mentions- (Page-3) The following sets are canonically bijective , (i) Set of homogenous quadratic polynomials in n variable with coefficients in $K$ (ii) The set of quadratic functions on $K^n$ (iii) The set of symmetric bilinear forms. (iV) The set of $n\times n$ symmetric matrices with elements in $K$. According to our discussion certainly (ii) and (iii) are not bijective.

Comment: I've just taken  a look at this page. A quadratic function is not clearly defined, in my opinion. The definition I recall is very general, and  the bijection is valid if $V$ is a free $R$-module (Bourbaki, *Algebra*, Ch. 9, *Sesquilinear Forms and Quadratic Forms*,  §3 n° 4, prop. 2)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will have a look at Bourbaki.

Comment: The definition "There exists a bilinear form $B:V\times V\to R$ such that $Q(v)=B(v,v), \forall v \in V$" (replacing both points above) seems more wholesome somehow.  [Andrew M. Gleason, 1966, _The Definition of a Quadratic Form_](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2314635?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: How do you find this bilinear form, given the quadratic form? *Bourbaki*'s definition seems to be more general: it is valid for modules over a commutative ring, not only for vector spaces over fields.

Comment: @Bernard:  A bilinear form as in the definition that I mentioned is clearly not unique, but it would be general for modules (though other than over a commutative ring would typically not be interesting).  And I don't think that your definition yields a bijection for an arbitrary free $R$-module.  Counterexample: when $R=\mathbf{F}_2$ and $dim_R(V)\ge 2$.

Comment: Of course, in characteristic $2$!